# Restart TLP service without rebooting system

Tags: power-management, battery, systemd, tlp

TLP helps make my laptop more conservative on power when on battery power, and more performance focused when on AC. The issue is that when I want to enable/disable TLP or change some settings with TLPUI, it requires a reboot before it takes affect. I've tried sudo systemctl stop TLP and sudo systemctl start TLP, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For changing settings without restarting, you should be able to (re)start the service with.

From https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/introduction.html#making-changes:

```
sudo tlp start
```

For changing the charge thresholds without restarting you can use the `tlp setcharge` command. It sets the charge thresholds immediately, using your settings if you don't supply any other arguments. On reboot, your settings are reapplied when TLP starts.

From https://linrunner.de/tlp/usage/tlp.html#battery-features:

> ```
> sudo tlp setcharge [ START_THRESH STOP_THRESH [ BAT0 | BAT1 ] ]
> ```
>
> Sets the thresholds to the given values. ... Without parameters the configured settings for the main battery (BAT0) are applied. Upon reboot, thresholds are reset to the configured settings.

Comment: Your answer is not the appropriate solution, `tlp setcharge` applies only the charge thresholds. To apply all of TLPs settings after a change, one should use `tlp start` --> https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/introduction.html#making-changes

Comment: Thanks @linrunner, I've updated the answer.